# Does WAS 8.5.5 supports EJB 1.x?

Tags: ejb, websphere-8

We have a requirement to migrate WAS 6.0 with EJB 1.x to WAS 8.5.5.with EJB 1.x. So wanted to know whether WAS 8.5.5 supports EJB 1.x.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it supports EJB 1.1. See this [page](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-dist&topic=rovr_specs) for all supported specs.